Check the content of an array element in expl3
Inspired of Check for duplicates in string array & Storing an array of strings in a command question / answers, I have written my own array handling functions below.
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\initArray}{m}%
{%
    \gcp_init_array:nn{#1}%
}%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \gcp_init_array:nn #1%
{%
    \seq_gclear_new:c{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}%
}%
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\deinitArray}{m}%
{%
    \gcp_delete_array:n{#1}%
}%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \gcp_delete_array:n #1%
{%
    \seq_if_exist:cTF {g_gcp_array_#1_seq}%
    {\seq_gclear:c{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}}%
    {}%
}%
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\appendArray}{mm}%
{%
    \gcp_append_array:ne{#1}{#2}%
}%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \gcp_append_array:nn #1 #2%
{%
    \seq_if_exist:cF{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}%
    { \seq_new:c{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}}%
    \__gcp_append_array:nn{#1}{#2}%
}%
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gcp_append_array:nn{ne}%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__gcp_append_array:nn #1 #2%
{%
    \tl_map_inline:nn{#2}%
    {%
        \seq_gput_right:cn{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}{##1}%
    }%
}%
%
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getArrayLength}{m}%
{%
    \seq_if_exist:cTF{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}%
    {%
        \seq_count:c{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}
    }%
    {0}%
}%
%
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getArrayElement}{mm}%
{%
    \gcp_get_array:nn{#1}{#2}%
}%
\cs_new:Npn \gcp_get_array:nn #1 #2%
{%
    \seq_if_exist:cTF{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}%
    {%
        \int_compare:nTF{#2<=\seq_count:c{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}}%
        {%
            \seq_item:cn{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}{#2}%
        }%
        {%
        }%
    }%
    {%
    }%
}%
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\setArrayElement}{mmm}%
{%
    \gcp_change_array:nne{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}%
\cs_new_protected:Nn \gcp_change_array:nnn%
{%
    \seq_if_exist:cF{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}%
    {\seq_new:c{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}}%
    \__gcp_change_array:nnn{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}%
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gcp_change_array:nnn{nne}%
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__gcp_change_array:nnn%
{%
    \seq_gset_item:cnnF{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}{#2}{#3}%
    { %
    }%
}%
%
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\countArrayElements}{mm}%
{%
    \gcp_count_element_in_array:nn{#1}{#2}%
}%
\cs_new:Npn \gcp_count_element_in_array:nn #1 #2%
{%
    \seq_if_exist:cTF {g_gcp_array_#1_seq}%
    {%
        \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int%
        \exp_args:No \seq_map_inline:cn{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}%
        {%
            \exp_args:Nno \str_if_eq:nnTF{##1}{#2}%
            {%
                \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int%
            }{}%
        }%
        \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int%
    }%
    {%
    }%
}%
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\processArray}{O{,~}mo}%
{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}%
    {%
        \seq_use:cn{g_gcp_array_#2_seq}{#1}%
    }{%
        \seq_map_inline:cn {g_gcp_array_#2_seq}{#3}%
    }%
}%
%
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \gcp_array_if_in:nn{ne}{T,TF,F}%
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfInArrayTF \gcp_array_if_in:neTF%
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfInArrayT \gcp_array_if_in:neT%
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfInArrayF \gcp_array_if_in:neF%
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \gcp_array_if_in:nn #1#2 {p,T,TF,F}%
{%
    \seq_if_exist:cTF{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}%
    {%
        \seq_if_in:cnTF {g_gcp_array_#1_seq}{#2}{\prg_return_true:}{\prg_return_false:}%
    }{\prg_return_false:}%
}%
%
%
% NOT Working Function
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkElement}{mmmmm}%
{%
    \gcp_check_element:nnnnn{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \gcp_check_element:nnnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 #5%
{%
    \seq_if_exist:cTF{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}% Check, if the Array exists
    {%
        \int_compare:nTF{#2 <= \seq_count:c{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}}% Check, if the index is within the array
        {%
            \str_if_eq:nnTF{#3}{\seq_item:cn{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}{#2}}% Check if the array element matches with #3
            {%
                #4% There is a match! Perform #4
            }%
            {%
                #5% There is no match! Perform #5
            }%
        }%
        {%
            #5% The index is not within the array! Perform #5
        }%
    }%
    {%
        #5% The array doesn't exists! Perfom #5
    }%
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\varTest}{test1}

\begin{document}
\initArray{roomArray}
\appendArray{roomArray}{{test1}}
\appendArray{roomArray}{{test1}}
\appendArray{roomArray}{{test1}}
\appendArray{roomArray}{{test1}}
\appendArray{roomArray}{{test1}}
\appendArray{roomArray}{{test1}}
PRINT:\processArray{roomArray}\\
LENGTH:\getArrayLength{roomArray}\\
\setArrayElement{roomArray}{2}{test2}
\setArrayElement{roomArray}{3}{test3}
PRINT:\processArray{roomArray}\\
ELEMENT:\getArrayElement{roomArray}{2}\\
IN-ARRAY:\IfInArrayTF{roomArray}{test1}{FOUND!}{NOT FOUND!}\\
COUNT:\countArrayElements{roomArray}{\varTest}\\
\checkElement{roomArray}{1}{\varTest}{Element is matching!}{Element is not matching!}\\
\checkElement{roomArray}{2}{\varTest}{Element is matching!}{Element is not matching!}\\
\checkElement{roomArray}{3}{\varTest}{Element is matching!}{Element is not matching!}\\
\checkElement{roomArray}{4}{\varTest}{Element is matching!}{Element is not matching!}\\
\deinitArray{roomArray}
PRINT:\processArray{roomArray}\\
\end{document}

This MWE works apart from the \checkElement function. I just want to test, if the input variable (#3) matches with the array (#1) element at index (#2). If this matches, I want to perform #4 if not it should perfom #5.
Why do I always get "Element is not matching!" even if the array element matches with the content of the test variable?
RESULT

EXPECTED RESUL
PRINT:test1, test1, test1, test1, test1, test1
LENGTH:6
PRINT:test1, test2, test3, test1, test1, test1
ELEMENT:test2
IN-ARRAY:FOUND!
COUNT:4
Element is matching!
Element is not matching!
Element is not matching!
Element is matching!
PRINT:


you are not expanding the \seq_item. You need \str_if_eq:eeTF or \str_if_eq:enTF (the later variant must be generated first)

Working! Thank you! :)

Your \getArrayLength function doesn't need two \seq_count:c, just one suffices, there is no need for the \int_compare:nNnTF check. Your \countArrayElements and \gcp_count_element_in_array:nn are not expandable and should be defined protected (or changed to not rely on assignments). Same is true for \gcp_array_if_in:nn, that isn't expandable.

@Skillmon okay the first topic I have changed, but the second topic regarding \countArrayElements I did not get. Could you maybe explain this in an answer?

This is not an answer to the original question, but a bit of code review!
Your current definition of \countArrayElements and \gcp_count_element_in_array:nn looks like the following:
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\countArrayElements}{mm}%
{%
    \gcp_count_element_in_array:nn{#1}{#2}%
}%
\cs_new:Npn \gcp_count_element_in_array:nn #1 #2%
{%
    \seq_if_exist:cTF {g_gcp_array_#1_seq}%
    {%
        \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int%  NOT expandable
        \exp_args:No \seq_map_inline:cn{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}% NOT expandable
        {%
            \exp_args:Nno \str_if_eq:nnTF{##1}{#2}%
            {%
                \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int% NOT expandable
            }{}%
        }%
        \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int%
    }%
    {%
    }%
}%

I marked each call to a non-expandable function in that code block. Because you're relying on non-expandable functions (assignments) your code can't be expandable itself, and hence you should define it protected. So using \NewDocumentCommand and \cs_new_protected:Npn.
In this particular case however you could change your code to be expandable:
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\countArrayElements}{mm}
  {
    \gcp_count_element_in_array:no {#1} {#2}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \gcp_count_element_in_array:nn #1 #2%
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cTF {g_gcp_array_#1_seq}
      {
        \int_eval:n
          {
            0
            \seq_map_tokens:cn
              {g_gcp_array_#1_seq}
              { \__gcp_count_element_in_array:nn {#2} }
          }
    }
    { 0 }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gcp_count_element_in_array:nn { no }
\cs_new:Npn \__gcp_count_element_in_array:nn #1#2
  { \str_if_eq:nnT {#1} {#2} { +1 } }


A similar issue is within your \gcp_array_if_in:nn(TF), the current definition is:
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \gcp_array_if_in:nn #1#2 {p,T,TF,F}%
{%
    \seq_if_exist:cTF{g_gcp_array_#1_seq}%
    {%
        \seq_if_in:cnTF {g_gcp_array_#1_seq}{#2}{\prg_return_true:}{\prg_return_false:}% NOT expandable
    }{\prg_return_false:}%
}%

Again you're using an unexpandable function (\seq_if_in:NnTF). Since that function tests for a matching token list comparison (not string comparison) an expandable equivalent can't be easily defined (since there is no correct expandable \tl_if_eq:nnTF alternative).
You can either resort to string comparison, or use the etl package to get something which is good enough at expandably comparing token lists for most use cases (see its documentation on its limitations; disclaimer: I'm the author of etl).
String based:
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \gcp_array_if_in:nn{ne}{T,TF,F}%
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfInArrayTF \gcp_array_if_in:neTF%
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfInArrayT \gcp_array_if_in:neT%
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfInArrayF \gcp_array_if_in:neF%
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \gcp_array_if_in:nn #1#2 {p,T,TF,F}%
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cT {g_gcp_array_#1_seq}
      { \seq_map_tokens:cn {g_gcp_array_#1_seq} { \__gcp_array_if_in:nn {#2} } }
    \prg_return_false:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__gcp_array_if_in:nn #1#2
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnT {#1} {#2}
      { \seq_map_break:n { \use_i:nn \prg_return_true: } }
  }

etl based:
\RequirePackage{etl}
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \gcp_array_if_in:nn{ne}{T,TF,F}%
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfInArrayTF \gcp_array_if_in:neTF%
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfInArrayT \gcp_array_if_in:neT%
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfInArrayF \gcp_array_if_in:neF%
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \gcp_array_if_in:nn #1#2 {p,T,TF,F}%
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cT {g_gcp_array_#1_seq}
      { \seq_map_tokens:cn {g_gcp_array_#1_seq} { \__gcp_array_if_in:nn {#2} } }
    \prg_return_false:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__gcp_array_if_in:nn #1#2
  {
    \etl_if_eq:nnT {#1} {#2}
      { \seq_map_break:n { \use_i:nn \prg_return_true: } }
  }


On your \appendArray request: You could add both variants of the code based on a starred form of the macro, like the following:
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__gcp_provide_array:n #1
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cF {g_gcp_array_#1_seq} { \seq_new:c { g_gcp_array_#1_seq } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\appendArray}{smm}
  {
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      { \gcp_append_array_items:ne {#2} {#3} }
      { \gcp_append_array:ne {#2} {#3} }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \gcp_append_array_items:nn #1 #2%
  {
    \__gcp_provide_array:n {#1}
    \tl_map_inline:nn {#2} { \seq_gput_right:cn { g_gcp_array_#1_seq } { ##1 } }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \gcp_append_array:nn #1#2
  {
    \__gcp_provide_array:n {#1}
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g_gcp_array_#1_seq } { #2 }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gcp_append_array_items:nn { ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gcp_append_array:nn { ne }


I have adapted this! When we are already talking about code improvements. Could you change the \appendArray function, that I don't need to use double brackets when I put the elements in? So \appendArray{roomArray}{test1} would be much better than \appendArray{roomArray}{{test1}}

@Pascal you defined it in such a way that you can do \appendArray{roomArray}{{bath}{living room}{attic}} to add three elements. There is no sane approach to distinguish this from only a single element. If you want \appendArray to aways only add a single element we can achieve this, but then you can't append multiple elements at once.

Hmm you are right, the multiple element append option is then not usable anymore… I don‘t see any use case in the moment for me but maybe it‘s better to have this option in the future.

@Pascal you can have both versions, see my edit.
